# Function running twice because event handler is not being unbound

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the TypeItJS library to make an intro to a game I am making. For some reason, after the second stage of the story `storyStage` is incremented twice because `storyAdvance()` is ran twice. I do not know why this is happening but I believe that it is because the function is not being unbound from the `#story` element. However, this is only a theory and it might be something else.

```
"use strict";
let story  = "";
let storyStage=0;
let resources = {};
let machines = {};

window.TypeItDefaults.cursor = "";
window.TypeItDefaults.html = false;
window.TypeItDefaults.callback = function () {
  $("#story").click(function () {
      storyAdvance();
  })
};
window.TypeItDefaults.speed = 10;

/*STORY FUNCITONS*/
function storyAdvance() {
    switch (storyStage) {
        case 0:
            $("#story").off('click');
            typeItInstance.type("<<Get Time>> SYSTEM TIME 3Y;345D;4x10^3AD || EARTH TIME : N/A <<END>>");
            storyStage++;
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#story").off('click');
            typeItInstance.empty().type("<<Send || Class : Report || Priority : 0>> $?Begin? Resources : Present // Surface // SubSurface // Deep || Water : Present // Surface // SubSurface || Life : Present // Class2 // DangerToLife || Assessment : Disengage // ## Reason: Following protocol 23-60-555 automatic disengage in progress, full destruction of presence of colony awaiting confirmation. ##$ <<END>> ");
            storyStage++;
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#story").off('click');
            typeItInstance.empty().type("<<Reply || Class : Orders || Priority : 14 || ##EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY## ||EstTravelTime : 1.23x10^6 Y>>$?Begin? Operation : ##Last Hope## || Override : Active || Orders : ##Prepare for sustained population in excess of 1 million persons. Adequate materials must be present. Disregard life readings.##$<END>>");
            storyStage = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            $("#story").off('click');
            $("#story").css("display", 'none');
            $("#resources").fadeIn(3000);
            storyStage++;
            break;
    }
}


// page loaded
$(
    function () {
        typeItInstance = new TypeIt("#story");
        $("#clickToBegin").click(
            function () {
                $("#clickToBegin").remove();
                storyAdvance();
            }
        );
        $("#story").click(
            function (){
                storyAdvance();
            }
        );
    }
);
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.google.apis.com/css?family=Curtive+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@5.5.0/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="DriverScriptV2.js"></script>
    <title>#Operation Last Hope#</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="screen">
    <div id="clickToBegin" class="clickable">Click To Begin.</div>
    <div id="story" class="clickable"></div>

    <div id="hintSection"></div>

    <div id="resources" class="no-select">
        <h1 class="sectionTitle">Resources</h1>
        <table id="resourceGrid" class="pointer">

            <tr id='tierIResources'>
                <td id="stone"></td>
                <td id="copper"></td>
                <td id="iron"></td>
                <td id="coal"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

div#screen {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.clickable div#story {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#resources, #machines,  #upgrades{
    display:none;
}

td {
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 50px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Cutive Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 13pt;
}

td#stone {
    background: #E0E0D1;
}

td#iron {
    background: #999999;
}

td#copper {
    background: #B26B00;
}

td#coal {
    background: #333333;
}

.no-select {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.clickable {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show the source of `TypeIt`, but it's likely because you're binding `$("#story").click` twice (once in the `callback` function, and once in the page load.

Comment: https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit would be the source for TypeIt. Callback is called on the end of typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created TypeIt -- thanks for using it! I think I've found your problem. On page load, when you create a new instance and save it to `typeItInstance`, that variable is scoped to the `$(function(){...});` it's wrapped in. Simply adding a `window.` to that variable will scope it globally, and you'll be able to reference it in your click handler. I tested this a little bit in a CodePen, and it appeared to be typing text as designed.

```
$(function () {
    window.typeItInstance = new TypeIt("#story");

    $("#clickToBegin").click(function () {
        $("#clickToBegin").remove();
        storyAdvance();
     });

     $("#story").click(function (){
        storyAdvance();
     });
 });
```

Hope that helps!

Update: Oops, just realized I didn't actually solve your problem. I'll check it out again later when I get a chance!